# How to send 'sender' to another method in objective C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, button, sender

I want to make a simple Circle and Cross game.

I put 9 buttons but connected it to one method so when the user click any of them the title of the button change to X or O. All the buttons have different tags. Now I want to send the 'sender' to another method just to check if the user is Circle or Cross

```
    -(void) show: (enum gamer) aGamer andSender: (id) sender
{
    switch(aGamer)
    {
        case gCircle:
            [sender setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",'o']];
            break;
        case gCross:
            [sender setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",'x']];

            break;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the button does not change the title. Here is how I call the method show when I click the button.

`[self show:aGamer andSender:sender];`

Comment: Why are you formatting a `'o'` to an `NSString`? You can just use `@"o"` instead.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the entire code of the method that calls `show:andSender:`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `setTitle:forState:` instead.
E.g.

```
[sender setTitle:@"o" forState:UIControlStateNormal]
```

Here is the link to the doc for UIButton: [Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006815-CH3-SW7)

Comment: That's only in Cocoa Touch. According to [this other question by the same questioner](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20961739/30461), they're developing for OS X, so they're using Cocoa.