# How to set title of the button?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I want to make a simple Circle and Cross game. I defined 9 buttons and tried to connect to ONE outlet:

```
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSButton *buttons;
```

Now I randomly choose a number from 1 - 9 which is computer move and I want to set title of the button by method:

```
[_buttons setTitle:@"o"];
[_buttons setTitle:@"x"];
```

I think it the problem with connection. I can only connect one button to one outlet no to multiple.

Can I specify the button by tag and connect 9 buttons to ONE outlet ?

Should I use Collection View Item ? How can I do this ?

My second idea is to define 9 outlets to each button but I want to avoid it.

Comment: My gut instinct tells me IB outlets aren't supposed to be one-to-many.

Comment: Does that set the title of every button?  (the code you have displayed)

Comment: Also, won't you eventually need 9 outlets anyway? You need to know which button is which to find out who won. (Also, choosing randomly isn't really much of a strategy in Tic-Tac-Toe :D)

Comment: I want to avoid adding 9 outlets. I make an array for moves. I implement an algorithm for computer movement but it isn't the point.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an `NSMatrix` containing buttons.  In Interface Builder, drop in a radio group, then change the style of the cells from Radio to Push.  Then you can have a single outlet to the matrix.  To change the title of one button, you could do something like

```
[[_buttons cellAtRow: 0 column: 2] setTitle: @"x"];
```

(Added:)

If you want to change titles in response to clicks, hook the `NSMatrix` to an action method like this:

```
- (IBAction) pushed:(id)sender
{
    NSMatrix* matrix = (NSMatrix*) sender;
    if ([matrix isKindOfClass: [NSMatrix class]])  // paranoia
    {
        NSButtonCell* hitCell = [matrix selectedCell];
        [hitCell setTitle: @"x"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I also use `[[button cellWithTag: (int)sender ] setTitle: @"x"];` firstly connecting each button to method ?

Comment: Casting the sender as an integer doesn't make it an integer.  But you could, I think, assign tags to the buttons and then use `[sender tag]`.  Actually, if you just want the clicked button to become x, how about `[sender setTitle: @"x"]`?

Comment: Doesn't work. Matrix of buttons connected firstly to NSMatrix and then each other to NSButton (as an argument) makes the buttons are disabled so You can't click them. I presume that we can't connect single outlet to the matrix and then each button to NSButton.

Comment: @user3133543, I don't understand what you are saying about "each other to NSButton", because I thought there was no NSButton, just an NSMatrix containing some instances of NSButtonCell.  But see my edited answer.